# Requiring Dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript function that I call using Node.js that I'm writing a bot with.

```
loadGames() {
    let games;
    try {
        games = fs.readdirSync('./games');
    } catch (e) {}
    if (!games) return;
    for (let i = 0, len = games.length; i < len; i++) {
        let file = games[i];
        if (!file.endsWith('.js')) continue;
        file = require('./../games/' + file);
        if (file.game && file.name && file.id) this.games[file.id] = file;
    }
}
```

I've noticed that after starting my application, this function will always load the same games, no matter how much I change the './games' folder (if I create new files or change existing files).

Why is it that my `fs.readdirSync` is not happening dynamically but is statically based on what the games directory contains when I start my application, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You mean you start your app, call loadGames(), add a new game, then call loadGames() again and it stays the same?

Comment: `require` caches loaded modules, so if you have modified a required `.js` file without restarting the application (or clearing `require`'s cache) subsequent calls to `require` will return the cached module; the modified `.js` file won't be loaded.

Comment: Are you talking of launching the app, then adding new files to the `./games` directory, and have the app respond to the changes in the directory?

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that one had to clear the require cache. Thank you!